# How this following "if statement" really works with the multiple "OR" operator

Tags: java, if-statement

I have little knowledge about the how the loops work.but the following program contain more then one loop and the **if statement** contain multiple **OR** operator.i am not sure how **exactly** the **if statement** works in this program, so some one please explain me.

```
public static void printSquareStar(int number) {
    if (number < 5) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value");
    } else {
        //Rows
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            //Columns
            for (int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
                if ((i == 1) || (i == number) || (j == 1) || (j == number) || (i == j) || (j == (number - i + 1))) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the if you start by checking in the left of every || whenever any of them evaluates to true  the if condition is done it doesn't check any more the whole if condition is true

Comment: What is the output of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((i == 1) - variable i is equal to 1?
|| OR
(i == number) variable i is equal to number?
||
(j == 1) variable j is equal to 1?
||
(j == number) j is equal to number?
||
(i == j) i is equal to j?
||
(j == (number - i + 1))) j is equal to number subtract i plus one?
```

If ANY of these statements are true, then the if statement is executed. The only time the else block is executed is when ALL of these statements are false. This is how the OR operator works.

Similarly the AND (&&) Operator is the opposite. ALL statements must be true in order for the if block to execute.

Hopefully that clears things up a little.